# ¿Cuál es el nombre de los poemas cuyas palabras, en su totalidad, empiezan con la misma letra?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, poesía

¿Cómo se llaman los poemas en los cuales cada palabra empieza con la misma letra?

He aquí un ejemplo de Francisco de Quevedo, llamado *Celebra a una dama poeta llamada Antonia*:

> Antes alegre andaba, agora apenas
> alcanzó alivio, ardiendo aprisionado;
> armas a Antandra aumento acobardado;
> aire abrazo, agua aprieto, aplico arenas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se llaman tautogramas. Para más información, ver [aquí](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautograma).